# How to create a functional HUD for iPhone game?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sprite-kit

I'm in the process of creating a mini iOS game to get my feet wet with Objective C. Anyway I have a working prototype, and a somewhat functional HUD. It shows the score, distance traveled, and the player's previous high score. However, I'm having trouble implementing how many lives the player has left. Could someone please help me or point me in the right direction on how to do this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help.

Here's the code I have for the lives and the HUD I've provide more if needed.

```
    - (void)startTheGame{

_lives = 3;
double curTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
_gameOverTime = curTime + 30.0;
_nextAsteroidSpawn = 0;
_gameOver = NO;

for (SKSpriteNode *asteroid in _asteroids) {
    asteroid.hidden = YES;
}

for (SKSpriteNode *laser in _shipLasers) {
    laser.hidden = YES;
}
_ship.hidden = NO;
//reset ship position for new game
_ship.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.1, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

//setup to handle accelerometer readings using CoreMotion Framework
[self startMonitoringAcceleration];

_highscore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"High: %li pt", [RWGameData sharedGameData].highScore];
_score.text = @"0 pt";
_distance.text = @"";
lives.text = @" 3";


    }
```

The HUD:

```
    -(void)setupHUD{
_score = [[SKLabelNode alloc] initWithFontNamed:@"Futura-CondensedMedium"];
_score.fontSize = 12.0;
_score.position = CGPointMake(50, 7);
_score.fontColor = [SKColor blackColor];
[self addChild:_score];

_distance = [[SKLabelNode alloc] initWithFontNamed:@"Futura-CondensedMedium"];
_distance.fontSize = 12.0;
_distance.position = CGPointMake(115, 7);
_distance.fontColor = [SKColor cyanColor];
[self addChild:_distance];

_highscore = [[SKLabelNode alloc] initWithFontNamed:@"Futura-CondensedMedium"];
_highscore.fontSize = 12.0;
_highscore.position = CGPointMake(200, 7);
_highscore.fontColor = [SKColor redColor];
[self addChild:_highscore];

lives = [[SKLabelNode alloc] initWithFontNamed:@"Futura-CondensedMedium"];
lives.fontSize = 12.0;
lives.position = CGPointMake(250, 7);
lives.fontColor = [SKColor yellowColor];
[self addChild:_lives];
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You seem to be doing everything else.

Comment: @sangony I keep getting the error Parse issue Expected identifier in my life lost function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If `_lives` is of type int and `livesLabel` is of type SKLabelNode, you can do the following to set the text of label node as and when required

```
livesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lives: %d",_lives];
```

also in the last line you are adding `_lives` to self, which is an int or NSInteger (whatever you have defined it as). It should be `livesLabel`

```
[self addChild:livesLabel];
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda hard to tell with the code you have posted but I did notice you use `lives = [[SKLabelNode alloc] initWithFontNamed:@"Futura-CondensedMedium"];` and then add `[self addChild:_lives];`

In your startTheGame method you are assigning 3 to `_lives`
 which obviously will not work as a SKLabelNode.

If that does not resolve the issue, double check if you are declaring `lives` as a SKLabelNode and not as something else.